# Patterns for Data validation when using a DAO

Tags: java, validation, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am developing a web application and am trying to determine the best practice for validating data before it is persisted.

I currently have 2 DAO interfaces:

```
UserDAOInt - defines what operations a user can perform, throws data validation exceptions

UserDAOPersistenceInt - defines what operations a user can perform, throws jpa exceptions
```

I have corresponding implementations for the DAO Interfaces:

```
UserDAOImpl - implements UserDAOInt, validates the data by making sure all data required is present, making sure that the entities being updated or deleted exist in the database. If there is an issue, an exception is thrown. If everything is ok, a call is made to the corresponding method in the classes UserDAOPersistenceInt implementation.

UserDAOPersistenceImpl - implements the UserDAOPersistenceInt. The only validation that occurs is checking for null objects returned by EntityManager calls, just in case they were removed between the time the validation occurred and the call to the method. Throws persistence related exceptions or Exception if a null object was returned by the EntityManager.
```

When the data comes in from the servlets, I validate the data on the web tier side before even attempting to use a DAO.

My question is, is it bad practice to validate the data on both the web tier side, and again within the DAO's?

I'm asking because I'm finding that I'm maintaining 2 sets of validations.

The validation that takes place on the servlet is the validation of the data coming in from the user, mainly in forms. If a validation error happens here, I generally use the text of the validation error as feedback that is presented to the user, for example, First Name is required, when filling out a form.

Once I make it to the DAO, I'm expecting for the operation to complete successfully, because I have 'vetted' the data within the web tier. Any exceptions that occur in the validation at the DAO level I use as the text that is logged, and then send a 500 error response, for example, but the underlying message in the exception is not something that I display to the user.

I would really like to only have 1 place where validations are maintained so that I don't have to make changes in 2 places, but I'm really just looking to find out what the established best practices are.

Answer (score 1):

I would hand this over to the bean validation framework. It allows you to manage the validation rules in a single place, as annotations to the bean, like this:

```
@Entity
public class Contact implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    protected String firstName;
    @NotNull
    protected String lastName;
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\."
        +"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@"
        +"(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?",
             message="{invalid.email}")
    protected String email;
    @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$",
             message="{invalid.phonenumber}")
    protected String mobilePhone;
    @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$",
             message="{invalid.phonenumber}")
    protected String homePhone;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    @Past
    protected Date birthday;
}
```

Validation will then be performed automatically during the JPA lifecycle events (PrePersist, PreUpdate, and PreRemove).

Manual validation can be done like this:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Contact>> errors = validator.validate(bean);
```

See the [JPA Entity tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#gkahq) and the [Bean validation tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html) for more information on what's possible.